# Is it possible to use RecordCount with Criteria

Tags: vba, ms-access, record-count

In [this article](http://rogersaccessblog.blogspot.ae/2009/04/what-is-fastest-way-to-return-record.html), 
It shows a comparative table how .RecordCount is way faster than any other method use in that article but it did not mention if it can be use with criteria.

That is my question now. Can `.recordcount` be use with criteria? For example I only want the recordcount to return numbers of record in my invoices table where status is equals to "PAID". If it is possible, How?

Currently I am using `for loops` on a recordset to do it but seeing that article can possibly increase performance if recordcount can be use with criteria

Thanks in advance

Comment: why dont you try it?

Comment: sorry.. forgot to mention.. If it is possible, How? (i do not know how to try it)

Comment: you can add criteria to queries in design or SQL. This gives you control of your `WHERE` clause that you require. Then open the query as a recordset.

Comment: If you want the records in an rst of say 1000, where the colour is blue, then red, then pink, then you can also filter this full rst and then get the count.  I'd look at recordsets etc. and get to grips with what you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your table is linked, use any method, but DCount is extremely simple:

```
PaidInvoiceCount = DCount("*", "InvoiceTable", "[Status] = 'PAID'")
```

The method in the link you provided is for *TableDefs* only and is very fast:

```
Public Function CountRecords()

    Dim lngCount    As Long

    Debug.Print Timer
    lngCount = OpenDatabase("d:\path\test.mdb").OpenRecordset("InvoiceTable").RecordCount
    Debug.Print Timer

End Function
```

You can modify this to use a recordset:

```
Public Function CountRecords()

    Dim rs          As DAO.Recordset
    Dim lngCount    As Long

    Debug.Print Timer
    Set rs = OpenDatabase("d:\path\test.mdb").OpenRecordset("Select * From InvoiceTable Where [Status] = 'PAID'", dbOpenSnapshot)
    rs.MoveLast
    lngCount = rsFilter.RecordCount
    Debug.Print Timer

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

End Function
```

but then it will run no faster than DCount.

Comment: I agree for the simplicity but the article shows that it is relatively too slow compare to .recordcount. Dcount takes 12 seconds to count 7125822 rows while .recordcount according to the article only takes 0.1 second to count the same quantity

Comment: For a local table, yes. But don't tell me, you haven't split your application into a backend with your tables and a fronted with all other objects.

Comment: I ran a test on a table with 800000+ records. Filtering on a non-indexed field took 2 seconds and 1 second on an indexed field took 1 second. Do you have 7 mio. invoices?

Comment: my application is split. the article mentioned the same outcome for linked tables.

Comment: i said the same argument with the client but they are actually the one who points me to that article and they demand to use it if possible. your test result with 800,000 records is indeed a great info. I actually do not have that much nor had ever created an app of that magnitude. the db im working on right now is only 20K.

Comment: I've added your options to the answer. If invoice count is a few thousand only, this topic shouldn't provide an issue at all. Your client should concentrate on matters where he/she can make a difference (how the application services the tasks) and leave the design details to you.